# Azure DevOps / Pipelines: Set the “Build Action” and “Copy To Output Directory” properties of a content file in a NuGet package

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I am creating a .net Standard 2.0 NuGet package and I want to deploy a config file and mark this file as “Content” and “Copy if Newer”.
When I install the package, the config file is deployed at the root of the project, but the properties are set to the default values: “None” and “Do Not Copy”.
I tried to solve the problem with an inline powershell script in azure pipelines:

```
- powershell: |
 $project= Get-Project Foo
 $project.ProjectItems.Item("foo.config").Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory").Value = 2
 $project.ProjectItems.Item("foo.config").Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = 2
```

but I got the following error:

> Get-Project : The term 'Get-Project' is not recognized as the name of
> a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program...

Is there a way to set these properties in a pipeline task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: there is nothing to do with pipelines. I just had to set the PackageCopyToOutput property to true in the csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="foo.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in the [Get-Project document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-get-project):

> Get-Project command Available only within the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio on Windows.

As a workaround, you can manually edit the .csproj file of your project to include the config file. See below example. Add below lines in your .csproj file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="content.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Update:

The content file resides in the root of my repo folder.

[image]

I have manually added below lines in csproj file.

[image]

The content.config file is successfully copied:

[image]

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not work. At least it does not work with .net Standard 2.0. 
This entry above is the default in the .csproj file when I set the “Copy To Output Directory” to “Copy if newer”.

Comment: Any error message from your azure pipeline. Please make sure the file path is correct in csproj file. I tested on a test net Standard 2.0 project in azure pipeline. It worked fine. See above attached screenshot.